# Is it possible for a flink job to read from a different topic at run time based on some control coming form a control topic or a file

Tags: apache-flink, flink-streaming

Is it possible for a Flink job to read from a different topic at run time based on some control coming from a control topic or a file

Answer (score 0):

Nothing prevents you from reading a string from a file or control topic and passing that string as the topic name to the FlinkKafkaConsumer constructor.

However, if your goal is to begin reading from a different topic after the job has been running for a while, I don't think that's possible. What you can do, however, is use [topic discovery](https://ci.apache.org/projects/flink/flink-docs-stable/dev/connectors/kafka.html#topic-discovery) to have your job dynamically discover new topics and begin consuming from them.